# Skype4COM get all recent chat's in recents

Tags: c#, skype, skype4com

I've made a code to get all contacts, but Now I would like to get all chat groups. Please do not read anymore of this topic if you have never used the Skype4COM API.

Used to collect all contacs

```
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < skype.HardwiredGroups.Count; i++)
            if (skype.HardwiredGroups[i + 1].Type == TGroupType.grpAllFriends)
            {
                for (int j = skype.HardwiredGroups[i + 1].Users.Count; j > 0; j--)
                    listBox1.Items.Add(skype.HardwiredGroups[i + 1].Users[j].Handle);
                button17.Enabled = false;
                break;
            }
    }
    catch (Exception eoi){}
```

Any idea to build a list of groups?

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<string> getChats(Skype skype)
{
    List<string> r = new List<string>();

    foreach (Chat c in skype.Chats)
         try { r.Add(c.Name); } catch (Exception) {}

    return r;
}
```

We have to try{} catch{}, because Skype generates invalid chats that will throw a COMException if we try to access them.

For a list box:

```
foreach (Chat c in skype.Chats) {
     try
     {
         listBox1.Items.Add(c.Name);
     } catch (Exception) {}
}
```

Then you can just use `skype.get_Chat(value)` on each item in the list box.

Comment: Hmm very nice, but now how could I make it add them all to a listbox line by line as my other code for getting contacts did.

Comment: Edited to add an example at the end. But just FYI, that will be the unique chat name, not the name you see in the UI. If you wanted the UI name, you'd have to use `skype.Chats[0].FriendlyName` (but you can't use `skype.get_Chat()` with the `FriendlyName` value) :)

Comment: Hmm @Josh that's the only issue is I need it to build a list of friendly names, PS: Thank's for the help. Not many here know much or anything about the SKYPE4COM so it's hard to find answers.

Comment: Agreed, it's a pain in the ass. You could easily change "name" to "friendly name" to achieve what you wanted, but I'm not sure about the best way to "ID" the user from the friendly name (especially as it can be changed). The best way I can think of is (in the try{} block, instead of what is there now): `uniqueList.Insert(listBox1.Items.Add(c.FriendlyName), c.Name);`, where _uniqueList_ is `List<string> uniqueList = new List<string>();`. Then you use `uniqueList[listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex]]` to get the username value of whatever is currently selected in listBox1. Hope that helps.